# Make circles radius react to zoom level

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

What I want to do is pretty simple: I want to keep the size of circles constant as the user zoom in or out.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) 
  })

  observe({
    new_zoom <- input$mymap_zoom
    leafletProxy('mymap') %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(data = data.frame(lon = 0, lat = 0), 
                 radius = 100000 / new_zoom)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried this code but I really can't explain the results. What happens is that every time I zoom in or out, the Leaflet will *add* a circle.

Why? Shouldn't `ClearShapes()` take care of this? Also is there any easy way to get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case i think you'de better use circlemarkers:

> Circle markers are much like regular circles (see Lines and Shapes), except that their radius in onscreen pixels stays constant regardless of zoom level.

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html